# Echarts map pinch to zoom on mobile/tablet not working

Tags: javascript, echarts

On a PC the echarts maps can be zoomed in by using the mouse wheel (OK).
But on a mobile/tablet using your fingers to zoom (pinch to zoom) it doesn't work - instead the map is moved and the tooltip is shown for the point that is pressed (NOK).

Adjusting a variety of options including 'roam: true'
Tried removing tooltips/emphasis - in case that is interfering with the zoom behaviour.
Searched for documentation on this specific thing without success.

## Working example with code/preview: https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=map-usa

```
echarts.registerMap('USA', usaJson, {
    Alaska: {              // 把阿拉斯加移到美国主大陆左下方
        left: -131,
        top: 25,
        width: 15
    },
    Hawaii: {
        left: -110,        // 夏威夷
        top: 28,
        width: 5
    },
    'Puerto Rico': {       // 波多黎各
        left: -76,
        top: 26,
        width: 2
    }
});
option = {
    title: {
        text: 'USA Population Estimates (2012)',
        subtext: 'Data from www.census.gov',
        sublink: 'http://www.census.gov/popest/data/datasets.html',
        left: 'right'
    },
    tooltip: {
        trigger: 'item',
        showDelay: 0,
        transitionDuration: 0.2,
        formatter: function (params) {
            var value = (params.value + '').split('.');
            value = value[0].replace(/(\d{1,3})(?=(?:\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, '$1,');
            return params.seriesName + '<br/>' + params.name + ': ' + value;
        }
    },
    visualMap: {
        left: 'right',
        min: 500000,
        max: 38000000,
        inRange: {
            color: ['#313695', '#4575b4', '#74add1', '#abd9e9', '#e0f3f8', '#ffffbf', '#fee090', '#fdae61', '#f46d43', '#d73027', '#a50026']
        },
        text:['High','Low'],           // 文本，默认为数值文本
        calculable: true
    },
    toolbox: {
        show: true,
        //orient: 'vertical',
        left: 'left',
        top: 'top',
        feature: {
            dataView: {readOnly: false},
            restore: {},
            saveAsImage: {}
        }
    },
    series: [
        {
            name: 'USA PopEstimates',
            type: 'map',
            roam: true,
            map: 'USA',
            itemStyle:{
                emphasis:{label:{show:true}}
            },
            // 文本位置修正
            textFixed: {
                Alaska: [20, -20]
            },
            data:[
                {name: 'Alabama', value: 4822023},
                {name: 'Alaska', value: 731449},
                {name: 'Arizona', value: 6553255},
                {name: 'Arkansas', value: 2949131},
                {name: 'California', value: 38041430},
                {name: 'Colorado', value: 5187582},
                {name: 'Connecticut', value: 3590347},
                {name: 'Delaware', value: 917092},
                {name: 'District of Columbia', value: 632323},
                {name: 'Florida', value: 19317568},
                {name: 'Georgia', value: 9919945},
                {name: 'Hawaii', value: 1392313},
                {name: 'Idaho', value: 1595728},
                {name: 'Illinois', value: 12875255},
                {name: 'Indiana', value: 6537334},
                {name: 'Iowa', value: 3074186},
                {name: 'Kansas', value: 2885905},
                {name: 'Kentucky', value: 4380415},
                {name: 'Louisiana', value: 4601893},
                {name: 'Maine', value: 1329192},
                {name: 'Maryland', value: 5884563},
                {name: 'Massachusetts', value: 6646144},
                {name: 'Michigan', value: 9883360},
                {name: 'Minnesota', value: 5379139},
                {name: 'Mississippi', value: 2984926},
                {name: 'Missouri', value: 6021988},
                {name: 'Montana', value: 1005141},
                {name: 'Nebraska', value: 1855525},
                {name: 'Nevada', value: 2758931},
                {name: 'New Hampshire', value: 1320718},
                {name: 'New Jersey', value: 8864590},
                {name: 'New Mexico', value: 2085538},
                {name: 'New York', value: 19570261},
                {name: 'North Carolina', value: 9752073},
                {name: 'North Dakota', value: 699628},
                {name: 'Ohio', value: 11544225},
                {name: 'Oklahoma', value: 3814820},
                {name: 'Oregon', value: 3899353},
                {name: 'Pennsylvania', value: 12763536},
                {name: 'Rhode Island', value: 1050292},
                {name: 'South Carolina', value: 4723723},
                {name: 'South Dakota', value: 833354},
                {name: 'Tennessee', value: 6456243},
                {name: 'Texas', value: 26059203},
                {name: 'Utah', value: 2855287},
                {name: 'Vermont', value: 626011},
                {name: 'Virginia', value: 8185867},
                {name: 'Washington', value: 6897012},
                {name: 'West Virginia', value: 1855413},
                {name: 'Wisconsin', value: 5726398},
                {name: 'Wyoming', value: 576412},
                {name: 'Puerto Rico', value: 3667084}
            ]
        }
    ]
};
```

I expect that from a mobile/tablet device I can pinch to zoom in - in a similar way as you would from a PC using the mouse wheel to zoom in.

Comment: Even I am facing the similar issue